# UIWebView Inside UIScrollView Html Links Not Working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have added a `UIWebView` along with some labels inside `UIScrollView` (using `StoryBoards`) by adding it as a `subview` and then setting the ScrollView `height` to show all the html content of `WebView` that is loaded in it using `loadHtmlString`.

The links in the html content are not working. A little searching revealed that Apple does not recommend putting `UIWebView` inside UIScrollView to avoid unexpected behaviour. But as i also have to add labels and other stuff other than the `UIWebView`, so i have to embed them inside `UIScrollView`.

Is there any way I can make the links work in the html content without violating and Apple's recommendation?

Comment: did you set your UIScrollView's contentSize?

Comment: yes of course i did that

Comment: It is working for me, I added a UIWebView inside UIScrollView and loaded @"<a href=\"http://google.com\">Google</a>" and clicking it loads Google.com

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are trying is not working?

Comment: I have retrieved a html string from a CDATA block using NSXMLParser and sent it to the WebView that is added inside a ScrollView. The html links "href" in the text that is loaded in the webview, are not working.

Comment: NSLog the the content your sending to the UIWebView to ensure you don't have parse errors and that the links are proper URLs.

Comment: Of course i have done that before posting this question. There were no parsing issues. In fact i was able to open html links of blog posts when webview wasn't added inside the scrollview.

Comment: Bottom line... your running into the Touch Event problem I mentioned down below. That's what Apple docs say is the issue your likely to encounter. See this stack post for confirmation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513130/uiwebview-in-uiscrollview-tips Me personally. I do stuff like that by putting those things into UITableViewCells. Then you get nice scrolling without too much work.

Comment: Did you find a workaround ? I'm having the exact same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to put a UIWebView inside a ScrollView. UIWebView will scroll and zoom and pan the content properly as is. It is sort of redundant unless you have some other layout reasons for example combining it with some other views.

The correct way to add your labels is to add them to a UIViewController or NavigationController and have them positioned around the UIWebView and to also add the UIWebView to that as well.

Comment: Yes thats what i wrote in the question that i have combined it with other views and looking for a solution.

Comment: Without knowing the design it is hard to say what is what but You might also consider adding the labels to the html content that shows up in the web view.

Comment: Its already done. I have added all my views (webview and labels) inside a scrollview. The reason i have added it in the ScrollView and not some other controller is that i want all of them to scroll together instead of separately. But the question is that the html links inside webview are not working and i want them to work.

Comment: Yeah there might be issues with the touch events going through to the UIWebView. The scrollview is probably intercepting them so that you can scroll it around. I saw Apple didnt recommend it and didn't look into it more deeply. If they go out of the way to say not a good idea to do something, I don't.